# localStorage in chrome extensions - Extension or page storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

If I use `localStorage` in a Google Chrome extension, is it the storage of the current webpage, or is it the storage of the extension?

Alternatively, how can I reach each `localStorage` independently?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage

Comment: @sachleen I know that, how is that related to the Chrome extensions?

Comment: @People why the downvotes? I don't understand them, really.

Comment: localStorage is localStorage, in an extension or otherwise. It's 5MB *per domain* so it depends on where you set it. I'm unclear on the second question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on where you use it. If you use it on the `background` or `options` page, it is of the extension, and it is shared. If it is from a content script, it is on the specific page. You can't reach the `localStorage` of each page at will, so if you want to do that, you should send a request to the background and store it in the extension's storage.

Note that if you're using the extension's storage, you may want to use [`chrome.storage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) instead.

Comment: `User data can be stored as objects (the localStorage API stores data in strings)` Ooooh! That's pretty nice.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Yep, and you can easily sync it too! No more hacks with making bookmarks and reading off of them to sync data (yeah, that used to happen)